# Facebook - OAuth Token - redirect_uri isn't an absolute URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

... but it is!

I am calling the facebook API with the following link in order to receive my access token:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.org%3A8080%2FServer%2FFacebookAuthenticationVerificationServlet&scope=manage_notifications,offline_access,read_mailbox,read_stream,publish_stream

What am I doing wrong?

Facebook answers with the following error:

```
message: redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.
type: OAuthException
code: 191
```

It shouldn't have anything to do with it, but I am using java's URLEncode.encode() to encode the URL into UTF-8. I compared the result with that one from JavaScript's encodeURIComponent() and didn't find any difference.

**EDIT:** Do I have to set the domain into my configuration? I can't locate it on "App Domains" (because facebook doesn't allow me to add domains there with port configuration) but I set the domain as "URL of my website".

**EDIT2:** The unencoded redirect uri: http://mydomain.org:8080/Server/FacebookAuthenticationVerificationServlet

**EDIT3:** This has nothing to do with the :8080. I tested it with a php-script (URL was  like bla.domain.org/myphp.php) and sent the code by the php script to the tomcat server, but the error persisted.

Comment: What is the redirect url you have given in your app settings, and what is the redirect url given in the auth script? Post it please.

Comment: it should be in the format http://example.com/folder as far as I know. I assume :8080  is whats causing the problem

Comment: But it worked once with that domain. I now changed my FB-password and therefore have to refetch the access token. And I have to use the tomcat server, so I can't put the :8080 away :/

Comment: Okay. It has nothing to do with :8080, I tested it in the way described in my main post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it turned out I misunderstood the OAuth protocol. I was fetching the authorizationCode that THEN leeds me to the accessToken.

But I wasn't able to fix that error in specific. I just redeveloped the procedure and implemented auth-code and access-token separation and it works fine now.

Maybe unauthorizating the app and reauthorizating it @ facebook did fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Error code 191 for Facebook is

> API Error Code: 191
>
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>
> Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Make sure `mydomain.org` is in the App Domains field, and that the Website with Facebook login field is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but no. At first, my error message says something different, but it turned out the error was somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't encode redirect_uri. `http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.org` is not understood as `http://mydomain.org`